# Encoding id and storing it as a unique code and store in table on creation of row

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, peewee, flask-peewee

Essentially, I'm trying to eliminate the need to show the id of a 'listing' to the user. I'm using [Hashids](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/hashids///) to encode the automatically created id as a unique code.

To show a single listing, I've been currently doing this:

```
@app.route('/listing/<uniqueHash>')
def listing(uniqueHash):
    a = hashids.decode(uniqueHash)
    listing = models.Listing.select().where( models.Listing.id == a ).get()
    uniqueHash = hashids.encode(listing.id)
    return render_template("test1.html", listing = listing, uniqueHash = uniqueHash)
```

and this works fine for a single listing. However, if I wanted to display multiple listings like this:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    listings = models.Listing.select().limit(100)
    return render_template("test.html", listings = listings)
```

I then can't provide the unique id for every listing to the jinja2 template (and don't see a way to encode/decode ids in the jinja template itself...is there?)

I'd ultimately like to store the unique code in the database, however am confused as to how to create the hashid - based off the id of the listing - when I'm creating that listing itself and don't know the id.

I'm currently creating a listing like this:

```
form = request.form
models.Listing.create(
    title = form['title'],
    description = form['description'],
    price = form['price']
)
```

I'm planning later to use this with WTForms for validation.

How am I best to include the unique code in the creation of a listing without knowing the id itself???

Any help is greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: I guess you are using peewee for your models? If peewee supports class based models you can use a function/property for the hashid on the model itself. Otherwise you can also inject functions into the jinja template i think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your `Listing` model, you could define a function such as:

```
def getHashId(self):
    return hashid.encode(self.id)
```

Now, anywhere in your Jinja2 template that you are using an instance of `Listing`, you can call `listing.getHashId()` to return the hashid matching the listing in question. This way, you don't need to store the hashid in the database either.

You could then simplify your `listing` function to something like this:

```
@app.route('/listing/<uniqueHash>')
def listing(uniqueHash):
    try:
        listing = models.Listing.select().where(models.Listing.id == hashid.decode(uniqueHash).get())
        return render_template("test1.html", listing=listing)
    except:
        #Listing with that uniqueHash does not exist
```